# Declared vector as parameter of a SAS function

Tags: vector, sas, cut

I am currently learning SAS, already knowing R and other programming languages, and I am confused about how to declare vectors.

I created a little function that would mimic the R `cut` function :

```
proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.funcs.trial;
function cut(var, cutoff1, cutoff2, cutoff3, value1, value2, value3, value4);
    if  var<cutoff1 then x=value1;
    if  var>=cutoff1 & var<cutoff2 then x=value2;
    if  var>=cutoff2 & var<cutoff3 then x=value3;
    if  var>=cutoff3 then x=value4;
    return (x);
endsub;
CUTTED_COL = cut(NOT_CUTTED_COL, 3.5, 5, 7.5, 0, 0.5, 1, 2);
```

The function works perfectly but is tied to this number of parameters. Here, var is a column in a dataset, and I'll use it to create another column with it.

To get to the next step, I'd like to add parameters as what was named `vectors` in R. I think `vectors` are named `arrays` in SAS but I'm not sure it is the same structure exactly.

```
proc fcmp outlib=sasuser.funcs.trial;
function cut2(var, cutoffs, values);
    /*loop over vectors with a do*/;
    return (x);
endsub;
CUTTED_COL = cut(NOT_CUTTED_COL, {3.5, 5, 7.5}, {0, 0.5, 1, 2});
```

Of course this syntax fails miserably. How can I write it correctly ?

NB : even if there is a better way than a custom function (I tried the proc format but it is not what I'm looking for), an answer to the true question about vectors and function is also very welcome for educational purpose.
NB2 : if the answer is RTFM, I'd like to know which part

FINALLY : here is the `cut` function I wrote using DomPazz's code ([link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47509848/3888000)). Works like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

DomPazz already posted the answer for how to pass arrays to FCMP functions. But your problem looks like something you should just solve with a format.  If you define a format like this.

```
proc format ;
  value cut 
   low -< 3.5 = '0'
   3.5 -< 5 = '0.5'
   5 -< 7.5 = '1'
   7.5 - high = '2'
  ;
run;
```

You could then use it to create your new variable.

```
cut2 = input(put(not_cut,cut.),32.);
```

Here is a worked example with both the format based solution and the formula based solution.

```
data want ;
  array cutoff (3) _temporary_ (3.5 5 7.5);
  array outcome (4) _temporary_ (0 0.5 1 2);
  input not_cut @@ ;
  do i=1 to dim(cutoff) until (not_cut < cutoff(i));
  end;
  cut=outcome(i);
  cut2 = input(put(not_cut,cut.),32.);
cards;
1 3.5 4 5 6 7.5 8
;
```

Output;

```
Obs    not_cut    i    cut    cut2

 1       1.0      1    0.0     0.0
 2       3.5      2    0.5     0.5
 3       4.0      2    0.5     0.5
 4       5.0      3    1.0     1.0
 5       6.0      3    1.0     1.0
 6       7.5      4    2.0     2.0
 7       8.0      4    2.0     2.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You can to declare the parameters as arrays (vectors).  Try this:

```
options cmplib=work.fns;

proc fcmp outlib=work.fns.test;
function cut2(var, cutoffs[*], values[*]);
   put var=;
   put cutoffs=;
   put values=;
   return (1);
endsub;
run;

data _null_;
   array cutoffs[3] (1 2 3);
   array values[3] (4 5 6);

    x = cut2(1,cutoffs,values);
run;
```

This puts the following into the SAS Log:

```
96   data _null_;
97   array cutoffs[3] (1 2 3);
98   array values[3] (4 5 6);
99
100  x = cut2(1,cutoffs,values);
101  run;

var=1
cutoffs[1]=1 cutoffs[2]=2 cutoffs[3]=3
values[1]=4 values[2]=5 values[3]=6
```

Comment: Thanks this seems great ! But this don't output anything in the Log window, is it normal ? I'd assume those `put` statements should log variables, don't they ?

Comment: Is there a way to directly declare the array in the function's parameters ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no.  SAS requires that you declare the array before you pass it.