# Reset a temporary array in SAS

Tags: arrays, sas

After I declares an array, I'd like to reset its values for the rest of the code.

```
array cutoffs[4] _temporary_ (1 2 3 4); /*works well*/
... use of the array
array cutoffs[3] _temporary_ (3.5 5 7.5); /*Error*/
... use of the updated array
```

The error is as following :

> ERROR 124-185: The variable cutoffs has already been defined.

This error is very clear but I wonder how could I reattribute the array without changing its name (which would be most tedious).

I tried some syntaxes but couldn't find by myself, and I saw no ressources on google, nor on stackoverflow.

How can I do it ?

EDIT : the main purpose is that I created a function (with `proc fcmp`) that take arrays as parameter and cut the value (like R's `cut` function). The function is to be used on a lot of columns but with different cutoffs, and I don't want to tediously create an array for each and every column.

Comment: Coming from R and other languages, this is surprisingly hard to find out.

Comment: You _do_ "tediously create an array for each and every column" since you each time have an `array cutoffs[x] _temporary_ (values)` line hardcoded in your data step. Using different names does not make it that more tedious.

Comment: Yes it does. I could copy-paste array declaration and the function and only change the values inside the arrays and the column to apply the function, but now I have to change the name of the arrays everytime. I'm not saying I use the best way since I'm a noob who started SAS less than a month ago, but I can assure you that this is awfully tedious.

Comment: I edited my answer to suggest another approach.

Comment: Not sure that FCMP is the right solution to this problem. You don't post it here but you asked before about your cutoff function.  It might be easier to create a macro instead for this application. Or setup the cutoff criteria as formats in advance and use the formats in your code instead of the lists of values.

Comment: @Tom Actually, my cut function works very well. You can find it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35397018/categorizing-variabels-in-sas-using-a-range-system/47509848#47509848) if you want to take a look. I tried also with format, works well but is a little less efficient (I'd have to write more code). I think I get the macro thing, but functions are a thing in programming languages so I'm more confortable with them. I would love to see a macro as an answer to the linked question though !

Comment: @DanChaltiel, if you post your function, we can probably give you a macro equivalent.

Comment: @user2877959 This is very nice of you ! It is in the link on my previous comment.

Comment: Added a macro based solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the values of the `cutoffs` array one by one.

```
array cutoffs{4} _temporary_ (1 2 3 4); /*works well*/
... use of the array
cutoffs[1]=3.5;
cutoffs{2}=5;
cutoffs{3}=7.5;
cutoffs{4}=.;
```

or you could just use another name for the array the second time.

With that said, the way you are using this seems a bit strange.

EDIT: you could consider rewriting your `proc fcmp` function to expect the list of values as a character string (e.g. `'3.5,5,7.5'`) instead of an array and do away with arrays entirely.

Your `proc fcmp` would change from something like

```
do i=1 to dim(array);
  val=array{i};
  ...
end;
```

to something like;

```
do i=1 to countw(array,',');
  val=input(scan(array,i,','),best32.);
  ...
end;
```

Comment: But will `dim(cutoff)` change too ? BTW, in every other programming language I know, this is not strange, I'll edit my post to explain a little.

Comment: No the dimension will not change. If by _"this"_ you mean _reusing a variable name_ then no, this is not necessarily strange. But defining a SAS array in a data step then later, in the same iteration, defining it again with other values and another dimension _is_ strange.

Comment: Don't use FCMP.  Create a macro instead.

Comment: @Tom are you telling me or the OP? I would also do this with macros but since OP says he is new to SAS and he already has FCMP down, I stuck with FCMP in my answer.

Comment: I tried with macro but didn't succeed as it doesn't return a value. SAS is very frustrating when you come from R, where all of this is very easy and well documented.

Comment: @DanChaltiel  "well documented"? R?

Comment: Let's start a war :-P

Answer (score 1):

Here is a macro version of your FCMP function:

```
%macro cut2string(var,cutoffs,values);
%if &var. lt %scan(&cutoffs.,1,%str( )) %then "%scan(&values.,1,%str( ))";
%else %if &var. ge %scan(&cutoffs.,-1,%str( )) %then "%scan(&values.,-1,%str( ))";
%else %do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&cutoffs.,%str( )));
    %if &var. ge %scan(&cutoffs.,&i.,%str( )) and &var. lt %scan(&cutoffs.,%eval(&i.+1),%str( )) %then "%scan(&values.,%eval(&i.+1),%str( ))";
%end;
%mend;
```

And here is how you would call it, using the same example as you used in your linked page:

```
data Work.nonsales2;
    /*set Work.nonsales;*/
    salary_string  = %cut2string(30000, 20000 100000 500000, <20k 20k-100k 100k-500k >500k);
run;
```

You could use keyword parameter instead of positional to make your calls clearer:

```
%macro cut2string(var=,cutoffs=,values=);
...
salary_string  = %cut2string(var=30000,cutoffs=20000 100000 500000,values=<20k 20k-100k 100k-500k >500k);
```

**HOWEVER** now that I see the code, this should really be a format in SAS:

```
proc format;
  values cutoffs
    low-<20000='<20k'
    20000-<100000='20k-100k'
    100000-<500000='100k-500k'
    500000-high='>500k'
    ;
run;
data work.nonsales2
  salarystrings=put(30000,cutoffs.);
run;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, I learn a lot by reading it. Too bad this was not my question because you would largely deserve an accepted answer !

Comment: Not sure how you could use that macro to cut the values of a dataset variable.  It I called it with `var=salary` to pass in the name of the variable it will compare the string `salary` with the cutoff values instead of comparing the value of salary.

Comment: Very true. This macro does what it works as far as the post it was taken from goes.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a macro instead of function?

```
%macro cut(invar,outvar,cutoffs,categories,dlm=%str( ));
/*
"CUT" continuous variable into categories
by generating SELECT code that can be used in
a data step.

The list of CATEGORIES must have one more entry that the list of CUTOFFS
*/
%local i ;
select ;
%do i=1 %to %sysfunc(countw(&cutoffs,&dlm));
  when (&invar <= %scan(&cutoffs,&i,&dlm)) &outvar=%scan(&categories,&i,&dlm) ;
%end;
  otherwise &outvar= %scan(&categories,-1,&dlm);
end;
%mend ;
```

Here is an example that creates both a numeric and a character output variable. For character variables either define the variable before using the macro or make sure the values for the first category is long enough for all values.

Let's test it.

```
data test ;
  input x @@;
  %cut(invar=x,outvar=y,cutoffs=3.5 5 7,categories=1 2 3 4)
  %cut(invar=x,outvar=z,cutoffs=3.5|5|7,categories="One  "|"Two"|"Three"|"Four",dlm=|)
cards;
2 3.5 4 5 6 7.4 8
;
```

If you turn on the MPRINT option you can see the generated code in the SAS log.

```
2275    %cut(invar=x,outvar=y,cutoffs=3.5 5 7,categories=1 2 3 4)
MPRINT(CUT):   select ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 3.5) y=1 ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 5) y=2 ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 7) y=3 ;
MPRINT(CUT):   otherwise y= 4;
MPRINT(CUT):   end;
2276    %cut(invar=x,outvar=z,cutoffs=3.5|5|7,categories="One  "|"Two  "|"Three"|"Four ",dlm=|)
MPRINT(CUT):   select ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 3.5) z="One  " ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 5) z="Two" ;
MPRINT(CUT):   when (x <= 7) z="Three" ;
MPRINT(CUT):   otherwise z= "Four";
MPRINT(CUT):   end;
```

Results

```
Obs     x     y      z

 1     2.0    1    One
 2     3.5    1    One
 3     4.0    2    Two
 4     5.0    2    Two
 5     6.0    3    Three
 6     7.4    4    Four
 7     8.0    4    Four
```